# dimension of the vector space

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $V$ be a real vector space. Let $W =\{u+iv: u,v\in  V \}$. Then $W$ is a vector space over $\Bbb C$. Then express $\dim_\Bbb C W$ in terms of $\dim_\Bbb R V$. Justify your answer.

Comment: Is there a particular point in the problem that you don't understand?

Comment: if S= {v1,...,vn} is basis of V.then S is also a basis of W .is it true?

Answer (score 2):

if $\{v_1 ..... v_n\}$ be basis of  V then $\{v_1,....v_n ,iv_1,....,iv_n\}$ will be a basis for W!
you can chek it easy!

Comment: But {v1,....vn,iv1,....,ivn} will be a basis for W over R not in C

Comment: ever combination of them over C will be in W you can test it you wil see!

Comment: for example (a+bi)v_1+iv_1=av_1+(b+1)iv_1 is in W becuase v\in V and so av \in V and so (b+1)\in V  then we will have av_1+(b+1)iv_1\in W

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: $\text{dim}_{\mathbb{R}}V = n.$ Let $\{v_1, \dots, v_n\}$ be a basis of $V$.

Claim: $\text{dim}_{\mathbb{R}}W = 2\ \text{dim}_{\mathbb{R}}V$.

Proof of the claim: it suffices to prove that $\{v_1, \dots v_n, iv_1, \dots, iv_n\}$ is a basis for $W$.

Let $w \in W$. By definition of $W$, $w = u +iv$, where $u,v \in V$. Being $\{v_1, \dots, v_n\}$ a basis for $V$ we have: $u = \sum_{1 \le j \le n} \alpha_j v_j$ and $v = \sum_{1 \le j \le n} \beta_j v_j$. Therefore, we have $w = u+iv = \sum_{1 \le j \le n} \alpha_j v_j + i \cdot \sum_{1 \le j \le n} \beta_j v_j = \sum_{1 \le j \le n} \alpha_j v_j + \sum_{1 \le j \le n} \beta_j iv_j$. This means that $\{v_1, \dots v_n, iv_1, \dots, iv_n\}$ generates $W$.

Let $(\alpha_1, \dots, \alpha_{2n})$ be such that $\sum_{1 \le j \le n}\alpha_jv_j + \sum_{n+1 \le j \le 2n} \alpha_jiv_{j-n} = 0$. Then we have that both $\sum_{1 \le j \le n}\alpha_jv_j = 0$ and $\sum_{n+1 \le j \le 2n}\alpha_jv_{j-n} = 0$. (Note that $a+ib = 0$ if and only if $a = b = 0$). Therefore, $(\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n) = (\alpha_{n+1},\dots, \alpha_{2n}) = (0, \dots, 0)$. This clearly implies that $(\alpha_1, \dots, \alpha_{2n}) = (0, \dots, 0)$, proving the claim.

This concludes the proof because $2\ \text{dim}_{\mathbb{R}}V = \text{dim}_{\mathbb{R}}W = 2\ \text{dim}_{\mathbb{C}}W$, therefore $\text{dim}_{\mathbb{R}}V = \text{dim}_{\mathbb{C}}W$.

Comment: it is correct but we have to express dim w(over c)in term dim v(over R)

Comment: if the dimension of $dim_\mathbb{R}W = 2\ dim_{\mathbb{C}W}$ then $dim_\mathbb{C}W = \frac{1}{2}\ dim_{\mathbb{R}}W$ :D

Comment: Question is "express $\dim_\Bbb C W$ in terms of $\dim_\Bbb R V$".you are doing : $\dim_\Bbb C W$ in terms of $\dim_\Bbb R W$.

Comment: omg, sorry :D I will edit in few minutes with the correct answer!

Comment: Unless there is a very good reason, we prefer not to arbitrarily delete good content: the answers could well help other users in the future.